# Bounties can make the profile reputation graph look silly

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, reputation-graph

A single day with a large negative reputation change can affect the graph's appearance more than I'd like it to. After offering a few bounties yesterday, my graph now looks like this:

[image]

This seems silly. For the sake of displaying single day's data, the scale is dramatically changed.

In a month it will drop off the default graph, but my all-time graph will look silly forever:

[image]

Personally, when I'm looking at my rep graph I'm more interesting in the rep I've gained, rather than what I've given away. The first improvement that occurred to me was be something like this, though wouldn't be able to display values when you've zoomed out very much:

[image]

Obviously this isn't a priority, but it's something that could be improved. Does anyone else have any comments or suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps bounties paid should be in a different color than reputation lost through other means.

Comment: Sometimes reality is silly. I think it looks fine; it shows what happened.

Comment: If you earn a +500 bounty, the horizontal axis will be centered.  Or do you suggest the same thing for incoming bounties?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: That hadn't occurred to me... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8):

This would be an *immense* amount of work for little payoff (in fact - it makes the graph less accurate).  While I agree it *can* be prettier, this isn't a way we'll implement, for a few reasons:

- Large time investment
- Customization of a third-party plugin
- The case of "offered a bounty" *and* "got up/down votes" on the same day (this happens very, *very* often) just leads to some very confusing numbers in the proposed display

Comment: I had this tagged as `discussion` because I wasn't sure what would be best and didn't want to make it specifically about my suggested implementation. None of your objections apply to Lance Robert's idea.

Answer (score 7):

They could have a button on there that if clicked would only show you positive net values.

<kbd>Positive Nets Only</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the graph should by default exclude bounties paid out, the interesting part of the graph isn't your overall score but the score gained via community interaction, though this can include non-bounty negative reputation, such as a really bad question that got heavily downvoted.